# How to set org mode to edit file when click on html file link?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

The default action when click on a html file link will open it in browser.

How to config the action of click to distinct web links and disk file link, so the web link starts with `http` or `https` will be open in browser and file link to disk will be open in emacs to edit?

Comment: The question is unclear: a link like `[[http://localhost/foo.html]]` will be opened in a browser; a link like `[[file:/tmp/foo.html]]` will be opened in Emacs. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @NickD My Emacs (`-Q`) opens it in `edge.exe` by default.  I use v29.1_2 on MS-Windows.

Comment: What is `it`? The `https` link or the `file` link, or something else - or maybe both? And what does `edge.exe` do with `it` (whatever it is)? I still don't understand what the OP wants and your comment did not clarify anything for me. Is the question Windows-specific?

Comment: @NickD Click at `[[file:a.html]]` in org-mode will open `a.html` in `edge.exe`

Comment: So it does (well, it opens it in Firefox for me, but I get your point). Thanks and sorry for being dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-h v org-file-apps`:

> Applications for opening `file:path` items in a document.

Its definition:

```lisp
(defcustom org-file-apps
  '((auto-mode . emacs)
    (directory . emacs)
    ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
    ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
    ;; ...             ^^^^^^^
```

You can customize it to change `default` to `emacs`.